# assertion- problems with internal call

Tags: java, android, junit, junit4

hi guys Im having some problems with my frist Testing

im writing this snippet but i keep get this problem:

> java.lang.AssertionError
>           at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
>           at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
>           at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
>           at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:722)

someone know hot to help me? and maybe also which are the correct thing to test in this class? thanks a lot

I already have Junit implementation in gradle

the test class is :

```
    public class QrActivityTest {

        public QrActivity tester;
        @Before
        public void setUp(){
            tester = new QrActivity();
        }
        @Test
        public void onCreate() {
            //barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(tester.getApplicationContext()).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();
           // Assert.assertNotNull(barcodeDetector);
            Assert.assertNotNull(tester);
            Assert.assertNotNull(tester.cameraSource);

        }}
```

the class is:

```
    public class QrActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        SurfaceView surfaceView;
        CameraSource cameraSource;
        TextView textView;
        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.barcode_scanner_layout);
            surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

            barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE).build();

            cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector).setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480).setAutoFocusEnabled(true).build();

            surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(QrActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(holder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(QrActivity.this, "errore fotoamera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


//this is to take data


                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                    final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                    if (qrCodes.size() != 0) {
                        textView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                                vibrator.vibrate(300);
                                textView.setText(qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                                if (qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue.equals("129063")) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(QrActivity.this, AttrezzaturaRecycleView.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    Utility.showToast(QrActivity.this, "Dispositivo trovato!");
                                }
                            }
                        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assertions check internal the values. If the assertion isn't met they throw an exception. So you might check the full stack trace.

The exception probably occur in the line `Assert.assertNotNull(tester.cameraSource);`. This is caused because cameraSource will be null. This is caused because you only create an instance of the class but no Events like `onCreate` are called. A simple Unit test isn't enough for front end testing.

You might need an instrumented test case. Pleas try to use the [JUnit testrules](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-rules) to instantiate the Activity. Concider that you need a device or emulator to run this tests.

Answer (score 0):

As @finder2 sais, the problem is, that `tester.cameraSource` is `null`.

I think, this is because the method `onCreate()` is never executed.

You may start your Application like normal or run `onCreate` by using Reflection.

You could also move the necessary code inside the constructor or a public method.